# .NET Marshaler: Good documentation?

Tags: .net, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm currently working on some C# code that calls into a custom, native dll.  When marshaling data back to C#, I have need to explicitly align the fields of the classes/structs used for marshaling.  I've had a number of issues with this stemming from an incomplete understanding of the marshaler and its rules.  For example, I recently found out through a SO question that the marshaler requires arrays to be DWORD aligned.  Had I known this earlier, it would have saved me some headache.

My question is two-fold:

1) Is there any good documentation for the marshaler that provides this type of information?

2) What other similar restrictions should I be aware of?  (For example, do all DWORD-sized fields have to be DWORD aligned)?

Answer (score 2):

There is a useful tool for generating the pinvoke signatures for a given library. It has shortcuts for win32 apis but you can pass in your own files.

[pinvoke interop assistant](http://blogs.msdn.com/bclteam/archive/2008/06/23/p-invoke-interop-assistant-justin-van-patten.aspx)

I'm not sure how much it will help with understanding of the mappings but at least it might give you working examples. I have used it to generate a C# interface to some of our native code and it worked well.

The [codeplex site](http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/) seems to have some useful diagnostic tools as well that I'm going to give go.

Answer (score 1):

http://pinvoke.net has a lot of good info, including exact marshalling instructions for many (most?) of the stock win32 functions, as well as many others.  It's wiki-based, so as you figure out new libraries or glitches with existing ones you can add them.

Comment: That is a useful site, but I'm marshaling data back from a custom .dll.  So, I have to define all of the marshaling struct/classes myself.  I've had some annoying issues stemming from not understanding the marshaler and its rules, so I was hoping to find some good documentation on the subject.